# the Cech-cohomology of the sheaf of germs of plurisubharmonic functions defined on a domain in C^n

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

we all know that if we consider  the sheaf of germs of a holomorphic functions defined on a domain in C^n,we have too many beautiful theorems characterizing the geometry of the domain by consider the Cech-cohomology of the sheaf.Then i think that plurisubharmonic functions is in some sense a  weaker function than holomorphic functions.So we may get some beautiful theorems as the case of holomorphic case,  for example if we can proof that for a domain in C^n,the first Cech-cohomology of the sheaf of germs of plurisubharmonic functions vanishes ,we then can choose any good plurisubharmonic functions as we want. What i want to ask is that have you ever considered such a question ,and i don't know whether this is a good question ? I want to hear some suggestions.

Comment: What is the "sheaf of germs of plurisubharmonic functions"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Petya has pointed out, plurisubharmonic functions on an open set do not form a group, so when one sheafifies, one gets a sheaf of sets, not groups; it has H^0, but no higher cohomology.

Comment: yes,you are right,i have not considering about the sheaf of sets 
but i notice that there are some sheaf theory of semigroups ,if in this sense , can we consider the cohomology ?

Comment: wangzw -- the first Cech cohomology (set) can be defined for sheaves of not necessarily abelian groups, but you really need inverses.